# Comparing each item in list to Other item in other list Python

Tags: python

[illustration of comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGgfX.png)

i got stuck on this code, can you help me?

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]

item = []
item.append(a)
item.append(b)

for i in range(len(item)):
    for j in range(len(item[i])):
        print('{} <= {}'.format(item[i][j], item[i+1][j]))
```

Comment: First let me commend you on your awesome illustration skills. Second, why do you use the list item? Why not just loop through a and b? Also are you trying to compare every item in a to every item in b? Or each index? Like a[0] to b[0], a[1] to b[1]?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `zip` to iterate over lists in parallel:

```
for x, y in zip(a, b):
    print(f'{x} <= {y}')

# 1 <= 4
# 2 <= 5
# 3 <= 6
```

Comment: But how if i have 3 lists?

Comment: @CSupport: you have the example for 2, for 3 you will have one more in `zip`.

Answer (score 2):

If you do it for three lists, It would look like this:

```
for x,y,z in zip(a,b,c):
    print(f"{x} <= {y} <= {z}")
```

Output:

```
1 <= 4 <= 7
2 <= 5 <= 8
3 <= 6 <= 9
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your illustration and assuming that the number of elements is equal on **a** and **b**, I believe the approach you are looking for is:

```py
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]

for i in range(len(a)):
    print(f"{a[i]} <= {b[i]}")
```

But if you want to obtain the result of the comparisson, you can do:

```py
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]

for i in range(len(a)):
    print(f"{a[i]} <= {b[i]} : {a[i] <=b [i]}")
```

Hopefully this will help you! :D